# Sub Nav links off a select tag

Tags: html

Consider the following menu

```
 <select>
 <option value="#">Home</option>
 <option value="#">About</option>
 <option value="#">Products and Services</option>
 <option value="#">Markets</option>
 <option value="#">Case Studies</option>
 <option value="#">Markets</option>
 <option value="#">Partners</option>
 <option value="#">Contact Us</option>
 <option value="#">Careers</option>
 <option value="#">News</option>
```

Is there a way to have sub menus come off certain options, for example a sub set of options off products and services, i.e security, government, private? Please excuse me if the question is outrageously ridiculous , Learning as I go

EDIT

Would using the optgroup label be the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `<optgroup>` tags or roll out your own (JavaScript-based) selectbox solution.